# SQL COUNT with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this table that lists which months each product is available on the market. For example product 1 is available from Mar to Dec and product 2 is available from Jan to Feb.

| product_id | start_month | end_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 10 | 11 |

I need to count how many product_ids each month of the year has but can't think of how to put: WHERE month >= start_month AND month >= end_month. Can I use a loop for this or would that be overkill>

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Will there always be at least 1 product available for sale in a given month?

Comment: @cod3-jr yes there will be at least one per month

Comment: @PhilNguyen cool. My answer leverages that to create the list of months. A bit of a kludge, but less code than explicitly enumerating the months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2M6nTbrY) to test out this solution.
It's dependent on there being at least 1 product available for sale in each month. Although, maybe it's better that a month isn't returned when there isn't a product for sale?

Could use @derviş-kayımbaşıoğlu approach to generating the months, but not group on product_id, but on month instead.

```
with months as (
    Select distinct start_month [month]
    from Product
)

Select m.month
    ,count(*) [products]
from months m
  left join Product p
  on m.month >= p.start_month and m.month <= p.end_month
group by m.month
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this needs to help but you may have syntax error since we don't know exact DBMS and version

```
select product_id, count(*) cnts
from table1 
inner join (
  select 1 month union
  select 2 union
  select 3 union
  select 4 union
  select 5 union
  select 6 union
  select 7 union
  select 8 union
  select 9 union
  select 10 union
  select 11 union
  select 12 union
) t2
on t2.month between table1.start_month and table1.end_month
group by product_id
```

Comment: This looks like it should work! I use MySQL btw

Comment: I think this is going to give you the number of months that a given product is available for sale. Not how many products are for sale in a given month. Because it groups by product_id

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you used UNION, not UNION ALL?

Comment: If there are a large number of product IDs, it's probably best to move the month list generation to a CTE instead of inline in the join.

Comment: @PhilNguyen I added mysql tag for you, next time do it yourself :)